# Performance issue (?) in calling MATLAB function from c++

Tags: c++, linux, matlab

I have a C++ code that calls a Matlab function by calling a command line argument:

```
string comm = "matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r \"matrix(" + to_string(N) + ", '" + fname + "')\"";

system(comm.c_str());
```

The Matlab code itself takes about 48 seconds to run. I determined this by using the `tic` and `toc` functions. When I track the progress using `top`, I see that the Matlab executable runs for ~55 seconds and then gets stopped. They still show up with status `S`, and the C++ executable itself does not show up:

```
14597 ia41      20   0 1980m 259m  83m S  1.3  0.4   0:52.96 MATLAB
```

After about half a minute, the Matlab entry begin to disappear, and the executable shows up. Is this normal behavior? I am using a linux machine with CentOS 6.7.

Comment: How much of the time is spent loading the matlab code into memory?

Comment: Does your machine have enough available memory to have both the Matlab code and your program in memory at the same time?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't know how much time it takes. How can I check? Also, I have ample memory, like 30 GB unused.

Comment: Let me clarify.  There is a difference between time spent executing code, time spent loading code into memory; and overall time from start to end.  The overall time may consist of loading time, execution time and any time spent being interrupted from the Matlab code.  Most of these items are variant.  So, specifically what are you concerned with?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I am concerned with the overall time. I am not worried about a few seconds, but when I try to run the same code 24 times at once in 24 cores, what ends up happening is that they don't run in parallel.

Comment: I know that you are asking for matlab, but.. a python with numpy could do "same" and it was lighter and with very similar syntax.

Comment: @Mquinteiro I was just curious. Worst case scenario I'll write the whole thing in C++. It's a small piece of code anyway.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate Some of your observations don't make sense. "After about half a minute, the Matlab entry begin to disappear, and the executable shows up. Is this normal behavior?" I'm pretty sure it still shows up, but you need to scroll down to find it. Or you can use htop which can filter by process name.

Comment: Anyways, Matlab is storing its code in a gazillion small files. It's not efficient to start it this way each time you run the function. I don't recommend reimplementing that code in C++ unless it's not very complicated; it's difficult to implement numerical algorithms in C/C++. As the other user said, maybe numpy or a native C++ library is more appropriate.

Comment: @o9000 I see. It's a very simple code that does some matrix operations. I'll look into C++ libraries that can do that. Thank you.

Comment: @o9000 When I call the matlab code from c++ this way, does the c++ code wait for it to finish before executing the next line?

Comment: Yes, system() is blocking.